# How to know if an app has been rated

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a game and I want to give an extra life to users who rate my app.

But how could I know if a user has rated my app or simply opened the review page and closed it from my Reminder? Is there any way to find out that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of the WP8.1 API doesn't provide such an ability.

There is one workaround [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457012/2681948) - it retrives the reviews from the app details page and then tries to match the data with the information about current user provided by Live SDK. Thought it may not be 100% accurate.